# bash search inside ZIP files with keyword?

Tags: bash

I am looking for a way to search inside ZIP files. My sysadmin gave me access to a mass storage device that contains approximately 1.5 million ZIPs.

Each ZIP may contain up to 1,000 (ASCII) files. Typically a file will have a name has a part number in it like so: `supplier_code~part_number~yyyymmdd~hhmmss.txt`

My boss asked me to search all the ZIPS for a specific part number. If I find a file matching a part number, I need to unzip that specific file. I have tried this so far on a handful of ZIPs:

> for i in `find . -name "*zip*"`; do unzip $i tmp/ ; done

Problem is that it unzips everything. That is not correct.  I tried to specify the part number like so (read the unzip man page)

> for i in `find . -name "*zip*"`; do unzip $i -c *part_number* tmp/ ; done

but it did not work (nothing found). And I got the correct part number.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. It's actually quite simple

`` for i in `find . -name "*zip"`; do unzip -o $i "*partnumber*" -d /tmp/ ; done ``

for example, this code

`` for i in `find . -name "*zip"`; do unzip -o $i "*3460*" -d /tmp/ ; done ``

will actually look at the zips on my device but only unzip the file(s) that match a part number.

Comment: The OP question is about searching. This answer does the unzipping. It seems it unzips all of the files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `-l` option of `unzip`. From the `man` page:

> -l     list archive files (short format).  The names, uncompressed file sizes and modification dates and times of the specified files are
>   printed, along with totals for all files specified.  If UnZip  was
>                 compiled  with  OS2_EAS  defined, the -l option also lists columns for the sizes of stored OS/2 extended attributes (EAs)
>   and OS/2 access control lists (ACLs).  In addition, the zipfile
>   comment and
>                 individual file comments (if any) are displayed.  If a file was archived from a single-case file system (for example, the old
>   MS-DOS FAT file system) and the -L option was given,  the  filename 
>   is
>                 converted to lowercase and is prefixed with a caret (^).

So try something like this -

```
for i in *.zip; do 
    echo "scanning $i";
    grep -oP "ixia" <(unzip -l "$i") && echo "Found in $i" || echo "Not Found in $i"; 
done
```

Since you mentioned you have millions of zip files, you probably don't need all the logging. This is just for example.

Comment: I tried your code. It works great but only display the ZIP file name that contains a file match. That does not help me. I need to unzip the file that matches the part number.

Comment: @AlanB Just change the line that says `echo "Found in $i"` to `unzip "$i"`.

Comment: This works just fine: ``for i in `find . -name "*zip"`; do unzip -o $i *part_number* -d somedir/ ; done``